What is this async request in wordpress
There is an issue appearing with high admin-ajax async request can anyone explain what this does, what this request is?
we have seen this multiple times but could not possibly debug or explain what exactly this request is? and any way to check

is this a request coming from plugin
Is this some kind of cron that is executing or a hook

Thank you

